# How to get Google Compute Engine free tier?

Tags: google-cloud, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-compute-engine

On [their website](https://cloud.google.com/free/) they announce a free machine:
[image: free tier]

However, when I try to get it, it is not free:
[image]

So, how can I get this free machine?

Comment: As far as I understand that means first month free, but that's far from "Always Free". On the page I linked it says: "Use these products for free up to the specified usage limits during and past the free trial. These usage limits do not expire, but are subject to change".

Comment: I'm not sure about what exactly these things mean. Anyway I just made this account, so I don't have any prior contracts/cards/debts with Google. And I did registered a credit card (even though I'm not sure this means I have an 'upgraded billing account').

Comment: Thanks for the investigation, I just did the "upgrade" following [these](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#how-to-upgrade) instructions. Hooowever, it still show the same stuff. =/

Comment: I think you might be right...this is the shortest "Always" I've ever seen.

Comment: In the end, it is just very confusing, but it is (until they change terms) "Always" free.

Comment: I closed this question because it doesn't look like a good fit for this site. It might be a better fit for [webmasters.se], [sf] among other [se] sites.

Answer (score 7):

You've got to take a leap of faith.

There are [two kinds of Free tiers](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions):

> The Google Cloud Platform Free Tier is your opportunity to learn and use GCP for free. It has two parts: a 12-month, $300 credit free trial and Always Free. The 12-month, $300 free trial allows you to use any GCP product. Always Free allows you to try participating products for free up to their non-expiring usage limits, making it easy for you to test and develop with these products.

Regarding the "Always Free" part, until the very end it's going to show you a price, but if you keep below the Free Tier specs you won't be billed.

Just to be sure I contacted their suport and was answered (bold added by me):

> I understand that you want to use a free f1-micro instance type but
>   **bothered to use it due to showing estimated monthly price of $4.28**.
>
> As you are eligible for ¨Always Free¨, 1 f1-micro is free of charges
>   per month as you can see on this link [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/free/). In case you get charges
>   using 1 f1-micro please contact our billing support using this link
>   [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/)